# Prevent iOS from adding a space/newline to pasted text

Tags: ios

On my iPhone running iOS 16.1.2, pasting text with the cursor set at the end of a word or on an empty line adds a space and newline, respectively. This is annoying. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

> iOS 16.1.2, pasting text with the cursor set at the end of a word or on an empty line adds a space and newline, respectively.

The default behavior is that a space is *provisionally* appended to the end of the text.  If you type another space, it will change it to a period.

If you are getting a newline, this means that a newline character was copied.

Comment: Cool. How do I disable it?

Comment: Disable what exactly?  The space or newline?

Comment: I want to disable the space.